# ERROR: cannot cast type integer to json in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, function, triggers

When I am trying to insert the record in `tableA`, i am getting the below error:

```
QUERY:  insert into schemaname.tableB(col1, col2) values(....)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function schemaname.funcA() line 5 at SQL statement
********** Error **********
ERROR: cannot cast type integer to json
SQL state: 42846
Context: PL/pgSQL function schemaname.funcA() line 5 at SQL statement
```

I have created following trigger which function when record gets committed:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER trg_name
  AFTER INSERT
  ON schemaname.tableA
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE schemaname.funcA();
```

In the below trigger function `col1` is of integer type and `col2` is of json type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaname.funcA()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

insert into schemaname.tableB(col1, col2) values(NEW.val1, json_build_object("abc", NEW.col2val1::json, "def", NEW.col2val2::json, "ghi", NEW.col2val3::json));

RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Could you please help me what could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaname.funcA()   RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$

    BEGIN

    insert into schemaname.tableB(col1, col2) values(NEW.col1, CAST('{"nameA" : ' ||'"'||NEW.nameA||'", ' || '"nameB" : '||'"'||NEW.nameB||'", ' ||'"nameC" : '||'"'||NEW.nameC||'", ' || '"nameD" : '||'"'||NEW.nameD||'"}' as json));

    RETURN NEW;

    END; $BODY$   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE   COST 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no cast from `integer` to `json`.

But since `json_build_object` accepts arguments of any type, you can solve the problem by removing the `::json` casts in your trigger function.

By the way, using `"abc"` as a string constant is wrong – probably an error introduced while trying to obfuscate your code. You have to write `'"abc"'`.

Comment: i removed ::json and then its showing the error near "abc" as 
ERROR: column "abc" does not exist.
I want to insert the data as key value, so i have used "abc" as a key.

Comment: Right, like I told you. You must put a string in single quotes.

Comment: I converted it into single quote. Now the error is ERROR:  function json_build_object(....) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: How does the function call look now?

Comment: @Nik: which Postgres version (`select version()`) are you using?

Comment: The version is 9.3.14

Comment: Oh, that explains it. The function was added in 9.4.

Comment: What should i use as an alternative? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Construct the string representation of JSON and type cast it to `json`. Better would be to upgrade to a later version.

Comment: `CAST ('{ "abc": || NEW.intcol || ', "def": "' || NEW.textcol || '" }' AS json)`